# Sorting alpha-numeric li from a node

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

From an html page I was able to get a nodelist through `querySelectorAll.`
After that through a cycle I got the node I need to work in so:

Given a node of a nodelist with this format:

```
<div id="search_filters">
 <section class="facet clearfix">
   <p>something3</p>
   <ul>
     <li>text1 abc-def 200-201<span>(35)</span></li>
     <li>text2 hjk-lef 203 <span>(11)</span></li>
     <li>text3 fgh 204 <span>(250)</span></li>
     <li>text4 sfsa 205 <span>(100)</span></li>
   </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

What i'm trying is to sort the `<li>` in desc numerical way.

For example, if i've several `li` text like that:

```
1) abc-def 200-201
2) fgh 204
3) hjk-lef 203
```

I would like to sort them like this (last number is what matter for sorting so in the case (3) what matter is 201):

```
1) fgh 204
2) hjk-lef 203
3) abc-def 200-201
```

I once though it would be possible to trim on a temp node the words and than sorting the number on descending way but than I'm having trouble on put the right order on the node I need to work in.

Any ideas?

Comment: When sorting `204, 203, 200-201`, is it the _first_ (`200`) or _last_ (`201`) number of `200-201` that would determine it's place in the result list?

Comment: last number i would say!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And post whatever you've tried so far.

Comment: Are you generating the `li` text from a data source? or are you receiving the HTML, to begin with?

Comment: i edited a bit the question, trying to give u more data, prob i was too vague

Comment: your html is invalid.

Comment: You need to check what kind of delimiter these `text`s have got. From the sample you've posted, I can see two: `-` and `space`. So by separating the `text` based on those delimiters we can obtain the last group which you may then use for sorting the `text`.

Comment: this seems to be a good idea, maybe i could try to sort just by using the last 2-3 numbers

Comment: can you use external libraries like lodash?

Comment: not in this case

Comment: Is there a range for numbers on the right, or they can be anything? Can the left string contain numeric characters?

Comment: Never mind. I think I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the way I got it working using the [sort prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```html
<section class="facet clearfix">
  <ul id="facet_67493" class="collapse">
    <li>
      <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_67493_0">
      <span class="custom-checkbox">
        <input id="facet_input_67493_0" data-search-url="#?q=Stagione-Autunno--Inverno+2014--2015" type="checkbox">
        <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
      </span>
      <a href="#?q=Stagione-Autunno--Inverno+2014--2015" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
        Autunno-Inverno 2014-2015
        <span class="magnitude">(1)</span>
      </a>
    </label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_67493_1">
      <span class="custom-checkbox">
        <input id="facet_input_67493_1" data-search-url="#?q=Stagione-Autunno--Inverno+2015--2016" type="checkbox">
        <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
      </span>

      <a href="#?q=Stagione-Autunno--Inverno+2015--2016" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
        Autunno-Inverno 2015-2016
        <span class="magnitude">(3)</span>
      </a>
    </label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_67493_2">
      <span class="custom-checkbox">
        <input id="facet_input_67493_2" data-search-url="#?q=Stagione-Autunno--Inverno+2016--2017" type="checkbox">
        <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
      </span>

      <a href="#?q=Stagione-Autunno--Inverno+2016--2017" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
        Autunno-Inverno 2016-2017
        <span class="magnitude">(27)</span>
      </a>
    </label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_67493_3">
      <span class="custom-checkbox">
        <input id="facet_input_67493_3" data-search-url="#?q=Stagione-Autunno--Inverno+2017--2018" type="checkbox">
        <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
      </span>

      <a href="#?q=Stagione-Autunno--Inverno+2017--2018" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
        Autunno-Inverno 2017-2018
        <span class="magnitude">(75)</span>
      </a>
    </label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_67493_4">
      <span class="custom-checkbox">
        <input id="facet_input_67493_4" data-search-url="#?q=Stagione-Autunno--Inverno+2018--2019" type="checkbox">
        <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
      </span>

      <a href="#?q=Stagione-Autunno--Inverno+2018--2019" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
        Autunno-Inverno 2018-2019
        <span class="magnitude">(203)</span>
      </a>
    </label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_67493_5">
      <span class="custom-checkbox">
        <input id="facet_input_67493_5" data-search-url="#?q=Stagione-Autunno--Inverno+2019--2020" type="checkbox">
        <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
      </span>

      <a href="#?q=Stagione-Autunno--Inverno+2019--2020" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
        Autunno-Inverno 2019-2020
        <span class="magnitude">(268)</span>
      </a>
    </label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_67493_6">
      <span class="custom-checkbox">
        <input id="facet_input_67493_6" data-search-url="#?q=Stagione-Primavera--Estate+2015" type="checkbox">
        <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
      </span>

      <a href="#?q=Stagione-Primavera--Estate+2015" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
        Primavera-Estate 2015
        <span class="magnitude">(1)</span>
      </a>
    </label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_67493_7">
      <span class="custom-checkbox">
        <input id="facet_input_67493_7" data-search-url="#?q=Stagione-Primavera--Estate+2016" type="checkbox">
        <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
      </span>

      <a href="#?q=Stagione-Primavera--Estate+2016" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
        Primavera-Estate 2016
        <span class="magnitude">(3)</span>
      </a>
    </label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_67493_8">
      <span class="custom-checkbox">
        <input id="facet_input_67493_8" data-search-url="#?q=Stagione-Primavera--Estate+2017" type="checkbox">
        <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
      </span>

      <a href="#?q=Stagione-Primavera--Estate+2017" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
        Primavera-Estate 2017
        <span class="magnitude">(61)</span>
      </a>
    </label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_67493_9">
      <span class="custom-checkbox">
        <input id="facet_input_67493_9" data-search-url="#?q=Stagione-Primavera--Estate+2018" type="checkbox">
        <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
      </span>

      <a href="#?q=Stagione-Primavera--Estate+2018" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
        Primavera-Estate 2018
        <span class="magnitude">(220)</span>
      </a>
    </label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_67493_10">
      <span class="custom-checkbox">
        <input id="facet_input_67493_10" data-search-url="#?q=Stagione-Primavera--Estate+2019" type="checkbox">
        <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
      </span>

      <a href="#?q=Stagione-Primavera--Estate+2019" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
        Primavera-Estate 2019
        <span class="magnitude">(433)</span>
      </a>
    </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

```js
const needle = "something3";
const selection = document.querySelectorAll('section.facet.clearfix');
let i = -1;
let targetIndex;
while(++i < selection.length){
  if(selection[i].innerHTML.indexOf(needle) > -1){
    targetIndex = i;
  }
}
const getNum = function(node, innerElement){
  const target = node.querySelector(innerElement);
  if(!target){
    console.warn("No matches for inner selector");
    return 0;
  }
  let haystack = ""
  if(target.childNodes.length > 0){
     haystack = target.childNodes[0].textContent;
  }
  else{
    haystack = target.innerHTML;
  }
  // console.info("haystack", haystack);
  const numericMatches = (haystack).match(/\d{1,}/g);
  const result = +numericMatches[numericMatches.length-1];
  console.info("RESULT", result);
  return result;
};
const ul = selection[targetIndex].querySelector("ul");
const lis = [...ul.querySelectorAll("li")].sort(function(a, b){
  return getNum(b, "a") - getNum(a, "a");
});
i = -1; // We already declared this above
while(++i < lis.length){
    ul.appendChild(lis[i]);
}
```

[codepen here](https://codepen.io/tonysamperi/pen/dyyYarg?editors=1011)

Comment: it's almost perfect! There's still a little "bug".
For what i see inside the <a> tag there's a <span> tag with a number and it seems it take also this number when making the sort. Is there a way to sorting with the condition that are only inside the <a> tag?
i updated the question with the <span> tag so it might be clearer

Comment: I don't understand. Please write the HTML in your answer copying the one I posted here and add what's missing. So I can adjust the code.

Comment: I see in ur codepen it's working like i desire! Still on my work it's having some iusse when there's the choiche between 1) 200 and 2) 200-201 it still sort in this position: 1) 200
2) 200-201.

i'll try to understand why

Comment: It depends on the content. The regex I made extracts the last sequence of characters in the source string. You probably have more than 1 childNode into your <li>. I'll made an adjustment to remove anything else

Comment: Try the latest update: I added a loop in the `getNum` function. You can copy just that.

Comment: i give you a codepen so that you can see it better : [link](https://codepen.io/costabrava1234/pen/PooPvzy)

Comment: Man. You're selecting the `li` cause in your first example there wasn't anything else inside. You gotta add a selector to match the container of your text. In this case `ul.querySelectorAll("li")` will contain the list, then you gotta search your content again with `querySelector`. Updating my codepen.

Comment: i gonna try to understand as much as i can for learning more about this, thank you very much!u helped me a lot!

Comment: Figurati! In bocca al lupo! ;)